# Math Round in VS C#

Tags: c#

so I have the following problem I'm trying to output 2 numbers after the decimal comma but it doesn't output it with 2 numbers only when I have zero or more than one zero at the end of the number.

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(s * 0.07, 2));
```

here's how I did it.

Comment: What is the significance of `0.07` ?

Comment: A random price that I have to multiply the variable... It is from my exercise's requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{s:N2}");
```